# Defining a function with counts(xs)

Tags: python

#### Assignment

> counts(xs):
>   Consider  a   sequence    of  values, xs. It  can contain duplicates, and we'd    like    to  know    how 
>   many  of  each    present value   there   are.    Construct   and return  a   dictionary  whose   keys    are the things  found
>   in    the sequence,   and whose   corresponding   values  are the counts
>   of    occurrences.
>
> - xs
>     ::    sequence    of  values. (It could   be  a   list,   a   string, or  other   things…)
> - Return    value:  a   dictionary  of  things  and their   number  of  occurrences in  xs.
>
> #### Examples:
>
> ```
> counts([1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,5])  → {1:  3,  2:  1,  3:  4,  5:  1}
> counts("abracadabra") → {'r':   2,  'd':    1,  'c':    1,  'b':    2,  'a':    5}
> ```

#### What I have tried:

```
def counts(xs):
    for x in xs:
        return {x: xs.count(x)}

counts(xs)
```

Comment: Please include all code/text in the body of the question, not in an image.

Comment: I've done this before, but the formatting gets all messed up, so I thought the image would be easier.

Comment: We can always help make the formatting clearer if you post everything - the important thing is to make the question self-contained so people don't have to click off the site.

Comment: I cann add it within the comments the way you want if that is easier.  Want me to do that instead then?

Comment: It's better to post everything in the question (hit the 'edit' button) rather than the comments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: *"I've done this before, but the formatting gets all messed up, so I thought the image would be easier"* Questions should be self contained. Also please explain the exact issue you are having. *"Can anybody help me with following these instructions"* is not an appropriate question.

Comment: I just added it to the edit question feature and formatted to the best of my ability.  Any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: Again, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code .

Comment: sorry Felix.. For one, I was getting things like just the "a" when using abracadabra, or when using a list of numbers, it only returned the first number.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the description of the problem you are having. We know what you are supposed to achieve, we know what you have tried, but we still not know what specific problem *you* have with solving this assignment.

Comment: Your sample code is not even valid Python and would not return anything at all, let alone "a". Please post the actual code you used.

Comment: The code as posted isn't indented correctly and has mismatched brackets.  If you have code that runs, post it exactly, along with actual output including error messages.

Comment: There, i tried to fix the code i have used again.  Here is what I used and it returns the first value of whatever I plug into xs only.

Comment: @Pownage27 thank you for your effort. Unfortunately, you can only [`return`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#return) from a function once, meaning that the first time you call it, the function returns the specified value and that's it. Instead, try building up your dictionary as you iterate over `xs`, then return the dict at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me, and is very close to what is given in the question. You have to return after iterating over all items (not just the first in the for-loop). Also, see that if I have an item 1 two places in the list i will add it twice to the dictionary (second addition overwriting the first), but that doesn't matter to us. It also assumes that all iterable given (xs) has a count method to invoke.

```
def counts(xs):
    d = {}
    for item in xs:
        d[item] = xs.count(item)
    return d 

if __name__== "__main__":
   print counts([1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,5])
   print counts("abracadabra")
```

Comment: It may work, but how does it work, and why? Code-only answers are not encouraged, *especially* when the OP is a beginning programmer and doesn't understand what they're doing.

Comment: @MattDMo. That was poor to give a minus in so short time as I was writing more during that time.

Comment: @MattDmo. What? your just handing out minus points to everybody?

Comment: Votes are given on what is there, not on what might be there in the future. If you mouse over the downvote button, the tooltip says *"This answer is not useful."*

Comment: BTW, I am free to vote however I choose (within the rules of the site, for example prohibiting revenge down-voting).

Comment: @MattDMo. I think it was poor judgement from your part, given time and also that you could have asked for more explanation in a comment first to give me a chance to elaborate. Also because I am new to answering questions (I am eager to participate more on the site) this would have had a negative effect. However, I am glad to see you removed your down vote.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.  The simplest is to iterate over the list once, adding to a counter for each value in the list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def counts(start_list):
    num_dict=defaultdict(int)
    for val in start_list:
        num_dict[val] += 1
    print num_dict
    print

counts([1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,5])
counts("abracadabra")
```

Comment: If you're using `collections`, why not just use `Counter` and be done with it? This answer does nothing to help the OP learn how to program.

Comment: Thank you, but I prefer to do this without using collections.  Matt, don't be so rude.  I am doing all of this on my own.  My friend took a class in this and he is just lending me all the work instructions he had to do for the class.  Once I take it next semester, I'm going to be ready! (:

Comment: Remember that you are here to get some help, so it's good that you don't let the self-proclaimed python gods interfere.  A little bit of searching shows this online book which has a section on using a dictionary as a set of counters  http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/thinkpython012.html#toc121  and hopefully there will be more in the book to help you learn Python.